# i have an error saying about UNSEAF_componentwillMount and it's not showing me the source file of that error

Tags: reactjs

Warning: Using UNSAFE_componentWillMount in strict mode is not recommended and may indicate bugs in your code

I have to go throw all my files, and I haven't found it serious that my functional component fetches first, then mounts.

Comment: You can type a single 'grep' command that searches all files: `grep -rI UNSAFE_componentWillMount`. But in my experience, the compiler says the location anyway.   It's possible the call is in some library you use, not your own code.